# How to convert nested ArrayList in Array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have to convert an ArrayList of ArrayList in to Array.

```
List<List<TockaXY>> clustersPorazdeljeni = new ArrayList<>(centers.size());
```

I know that is possible to convert a single ArrayList to Array like

```
 TockaXY[] arrayOfClusters = clustersPorazdeljeni.toArray(new TockaXY[centers.size()]);
```

But these does not convert the nested part. As i understand is now array of ArrayLists. So is it possible to get an Array out of nested ArrayLists?

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question). To answer your question: yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is linear alternative for flatMap():

```
    List<List<TockaXY>> clustersPorazdeljeni = new ArrayList<>();

    List<TockaXY> flatArray = new ArrayList<>();
    clustersPorazdeljeni.forEach(flatArray::addAll);
    TockaXY[] arrayOfClusters = flatArray.toArray(new TockaXY[0]);
```

Or with flatMap:

```
TockaXY[] arrayOfClusters = clustersPorazdeljeni.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).toArray(TockaXY[]::new);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use flatMap:

```
List<List<TockaXY>> clustersPorazdeljeni = new ArrayList<>();
TockaXY[] flattened = clustersPorazdeljeni.stream()
        .flatMap(x -> x.stream())
        .toArray(x -> new TockaXY[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible using Java `Stream` and [`Stream::flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) :

```
List<List<TockaXY>> clustersPorazdeljeni = new ArrayList<>();

TockaXY[] strings = clustersPorazdeljeni.stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .toArray(TockaXY[]::new);
```